# Checking if I'm in Network Local but without Internet, Android

Tags: android

How Can I only Know if I'm connected in Network Local but without connection to Internet , or without receive data? I'm trying get a method that can check it ... Help me please I'm working in Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it

Check if network is available like this

**function 1**

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

After this, check like this if internet is available

**function 2**

```
 public static boolean isInternetAccessible(Context context) {
     if (isWifiAvailable()) {
         try {
             HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500); 
            urlc.connect();
            return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Couldn't check internet connection", e);
        }
       } else {
           Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Internet not available!");
       }
   return false;
}
```

1. If function 1 returns false --> Not connected to network
2. If function 1 return true and function 2 returns false --> Connected but no intenet
3. If both functions return true --> Internet is accessible

**Note** You will need these two permissions in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I tested it and it works great, Thanks a lot Rohit5k2

Comment: How would you do this with an async task? where I want the boolean value returned back to the activity that called it.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you are allowed to access the internet from your APP.

The permission for that is defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
Make sure you have the below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Code Method

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000);
urlc.connect();
Log.i(Tag,Integer.toString(urlc.getResponseCode()));
```