# What is the best way to check internet connection in Android?

Tags: android

I'm using these code in an `AsyncTask` to check Internet connection:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
    //toast show
            }
```

This code isn't working on some device like most of Huawei models, and Samsung Galaxy Note 3.

Also, if user has Internet connection with data like GPRS ، EDGE ، 3G, 4G ...

What is the best code to check internet connection to support on all device and all kind of connections?

Comment: I have answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349382/checking-if-im-in-network-local-but-without-internet-android/28349527#28349527 See if this works for you.

Comment: Also dont forget to add these permissions - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this class :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {

   private Context _context;

   public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
       this._context = context;
   }

   public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
       ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         if (connectivity != null)
         {
             NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
             if (info != null)
                 for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                     if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                     {
                         return true;
                     }

         }
         return false;
   }

}
```

Now, in your class :

```
ConnectionDetector  con = new ConnectionDetector ();

if(con.isConnectingToInternet()){
.
.
.
}
```

In your `manifest.xml` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create asynctask

```
public class IsInternetConnected extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
private Context context;
private InternetCheckListener listener;

public IsInternetConnected(Context context, InternetCheckListener listener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        try{
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(3000); //choose your own timeframe
            connection.setReadTimeout(4000); //choose your own timeframe
            connection.connect();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == 200) { //Connection OK
                return true;
            } else {
                return  false;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            return  false; //connectivity exists, but no internet.
        }
    } else {
        return  false; //no connectivity
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isConnected) {
    super.onPostExecute(isConnected);
    listener.onInternetConnect(isConnected);
}
```

}

Create interface InternetCheckListener

```
public interface InternetCheckListener {
void onInternetConnect(boolean isConnected);
```

}

Now, Called AsyncTask in Activity class

```
new IsInternetConnected(this, new InternetCheckListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInternetConnect(boolean isConnected) {
         Toast.makeText(TestingActivity.this, "Internet Connected : " + isConnected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}).execute();
```

In Manifiest file add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static boolean hasConnection(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

then in Activity

```
        if(hasConnection(getApplicationContext()))
        {
            new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://yoursite.com");
        }
        else
        {
        //no network connection
        }
```

add permission in manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```